# SSH command in a bash script isn't run when the script is executed by an application

Tags: bash, ssh, pgpool

I'm using PG pool, which executes a failover script when a database node goes down. The script needs to touch a certain file on the new master and make some changes on the old master. It works fine when I run it, but it doesn't when run by the application. I know the script is being executed appropriately as it sends me an email with the host details. Keys are set-up so passwords aren't required.

The script is as follows:

```
#! /bin/sh

OLD_HOST=$1
NEW_HOST=$2

# new host: touch trigger file
/usr/bin/ssh -T root@$NEW_HOST /bin/touch /mirror/pg_trigger/trigger

# old host: remove trigger file
/usr/bin/ssh -T root@$OLD_HOST /bin/rm /mirror/pg_trigger/trigger -f

# old host: rename recovery.done to recovery.conf
/usr/bin/ssh -T root@$OLD_HOST /bin/mv /opt/postgres/9.1/data/recovery.done /opt/postgres /9.1/data/recovery.conf -f
```

It doesn't even work if the old/new host is the local machine. I have a feeling this has to do with it being run via the pgpool user, but I'm really not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: running ssh in '-vvv' mode and checking exit codes may help to see what fails and why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run it manually, do you run as the `pgpool` user? SSH keys are per user so if you are running as a different account, you will get different results.

You could also try the `-i <keypath>` flag with SSH to explicitly pass the path to your key.

Comment: No, I'm running as root. This is likely to be issue, I'll test it out now.